# How to use the same animation clip for Multiple objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 simple buttons, every 10 seconds I want one of them to animate (Shake movement along the X axis left and right) for just 2 seconds.

[2 Buttons Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijl72.png)

So I have created a single animator controller and ONE animation clip in Unity for the shake animation on the **First Button** and that worked just fine but for the **Second Button** things went wrong because the second button snaps to the **First Button's** location and then apply the animation.

Now I know whats causing this problem which is that in the animation clip i'm moving the
**First Button** from its X position (X = 413) left and right whereas the **Second Button's** X position is (X = 640), which means the **Second Button** will snap to (X = 413) to apply the animation.

**My question is: Is it possible to apply the same animation clip to different objects? Or I have to create the animation clip using another software and the use it in unity?**

Comment: are you using root  motion?

Comment: No i'm not, any suggestions?

Comment: rather use a parent object, move that one in your scene and animate only the children's relative positions to that parent object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to apply the same animation clip to different objects?

Yes.

But without seeing your code and your exact setup, it is difficult to give a confident solution to your problem. However, I am *fairly* confident that your problem is the very same one that I experienced recently.

Before I give you the solution, allow me to explain the cause of the problem (assuming that we are talking about the same problem):

When you animate an object, let's say for argument's sake the `position` of a `Transform` component, you are animating it **absolutely**. In other words, if a key-frame moves the transform along the x axis by '5', what is *really* happening is **not** a relative movement, but an **absolute** one, wherein '5' is added to the current position *absolutely*.

So, if the starting position is (125, 0), then the animation leaves it as (130, 0) in this case (since we're moving by '5' on the x). If you then decide that you want to move the animated object to a different location on the screen, let's say to (250, 0), you will find that once this animation starts playing, that it will snap the object back to (125, 0) to play the animation.

As you can probably guess, this would happen because the first key-frame in the animation states that the position is to be at (125, 0). It doesn't care (and doesn't even know) that the object itself is now at (250 ,0).

I know you touched on this in your question but I just wanted to make it as clear as possible.

Okay, hopefully I've explained the cause of the problem, now for a solution:

*Parent an empty `GameObject` to the object that you are trying to animate.*

With that done, when you animate the button's position, the movement will be *relative* to the parent instead of absolute.

Note: You may need to redo you animation after this change though to make it so that the button goes from (0, 0) to (5, 0). Then when you add more buttons you can reuse the animation, just make sure they are parented to another `GameObject` and are positioned at (0, 0).